# C++ Assigning float to member data

Tags: c++

I have a custom Vector class that contains an x, y, and z. These are stored in an int array called `data`. So basically `data[0] = x`, `data[1] = y`, and `data[2] = z`. Simple enough.

I am tasked with writing a function that allows the following:

```
vector[0] = 2.0f;
```

Which should make the x value of the vector be `2.0`. I've already overloaded the [ ] operator so that it returns a float (it's essentially a getter method - ex:

```
cout << vector[0];
```

Would print whatever the x value of vector is.)

I'm confused as to how I can assign the float to the `x`, `y` or `z`. I think I need to overload an operator (perhaps the =), but I am not sure. Am I thinking about this the right way?

Comment: What would / should happen were you to do `vector[0] = 2.5f;` followed by `cout << vector[0];`?

Comment: Then storing the underlying data in an array of `int` won't help you much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you need to provide a version of `operator[]` that returns a reference to the member that you want to be assignable to. For example:

```
class vector {
public:
    float& operator[](int pos) {
        return data[pos];
    }
    //You should also provide a const qualified overload
    //so that operator[] can be called on a const vector
    float operator[](int pos) const {
        return data[pos];
    }
private:
    float data[3];
};
```

Comment: I appreciate the reply! I already have that function written and it works. I guess my question is more how should I overload 'operator =' to get it to work with this?

Comment: There is no need to overload `operator=`, as the function returns a reference to a float. floats are built in types which already have `operator=` defined for them.